# match 2 collection on a field and than find docs if price is lower than out to a new collection in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

**`col a`** :

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6402fd80ac80190371cda444"
  },
  "asinno": "B096V2J37X",
  "urunisim": "TOSHIBA 65UA3A63DT ",
  "fiyat": 14485.48
}
```

**`col b`** :

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63feef705572f69c3986f085"
  },
  "asinno": "B096V2J37X",
  "urunisim": "TOSHIBA 65UA3A63DT ",
  "fiyat": 11909.99
}
```

as you see match the collection on asin field than find if colb.fiyat lt cola.fiyat
out the result as new collection

```
a.aggregate[
    {
      $lookup:
         {
          from: "b",
          localField: "asinno",
          foreignField: "asinno",
          as: "result",
        },
    },
    {
      $match:
        /**
         * query: The query in MQL.
         */
        {
          $expr: {
            $lt: ["$result.fiyat", "$fiyat"],
          },
        },
    },
  ]
```

here is my code but it gives error

> ```
> PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: operation
> exceeded time limit
> ```

when i increase the limit also gives same error
Any faster way for this to sort? Coz both collections have over 600k docs

Answer (score 0):

```
     [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "b",
            localField: "asinno",
            foreignField: "asinno",
            as: "result",
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind:
            {
              path: "$result",
            },
        },
        {
          $match:
            {
              $expr: {
                $lt: ["$result.fiyat", "$fiyat"],
              },
            },
        },
        {
          $out:
            "urun6-7",
        },
      ]
```

$unwind solved my problem but still need speed.Any suggestion?

Comment: Add indexes to the `asinno` field in both collections to speed up the matching process

Comment: Yea i did but still very very slow.Been 4-5 hours still processing.

Comment: Use `$project` stage to filter the results and return only the required fields instead of using `$match`. If it does not work, you can consider sharding your collections to distribute the load across multiple servers.

Comment: deleted all indexes and created all fields with regular asc type.Problem solved , around 2 mins got the result.